# AWS/EC2 - Initially working instances, become inaccessible, although still running.

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

**Issue in a nutshell:**

Simple-singular-practice ec2 instances are unexpectedly just falling off the grid even though they are still running, and I have to keep recreating them ,and if not, ssh accessing or online public DNS accessing will result in a **"Timeout"**.

**Little More Details Outside the Nutshell :)**

I've followed the [setting up a LAMP server instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) to the "T" and successfully have served up basic HTML pages.

**Everything initially works fine:**

- I can ssh into the instance no problem
- When accessing the public DNS online - the expected html pages render   just fine.

**Problem:**

But then, quiet randomly, I can no longer access the instance through ssh and even online, the public DNS is inaccessible.

**In both cases they just "Timeout"**

**Config:**

- Basic Free Tier
- Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type
- t2.micro
- Number of Instances - 1
- Auto-assign Public IP(Enabled)
- Ports - 22(My IP),80(0.0.0.0),443(0.0.0.0)
- Using a key pair

**Question:**

What typically causes instances freezing up like this?

Comment: What is the output of `ssh -v` when the instance is not accessible? Did you stop and start the instance?

Comment: @helloV                                                                                                ssh<my input> -v output this:                                                        OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-88-131-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.88.131.182] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54.88.131.182 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-54-88-131-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Also after I launched it - I never stopped it.

Answer (score 0):

LAMP stacks on EC2 are extremely common, and the guide you're following is extremely popular and has been used for years so it's likely you've gone wrong somewhere or the problem is something more sinister.

If you can't access the instance by any means, it would sound like it has become overloaded. Unless you've accidentally changed a firewall rule on the AWS side (eg. Security Groups, NACLS) or something on the instance level (eg. IP Tables).

Open up ICMP on your security group and try pinging the instance and see if you get a response.

After you've verified all your firewalls and you've tried to connect to it through every means, check out the logs, they're your friend.

To check the logs, start at the AWS level. CloudWatch records lots of data about your instance - CPU Utilization, Network In & Out and more. Check all of these through the AWS Console ensuring you select the "Maximum" statistic and not "Average". Also, take a look at the "StatusCheckFailed_System" (Hardware problem) and "StatusCheckFailed_Instance" (Instance not responding to health check probes) metrics to see if they have any story to tell. See the docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SingleMetricPerInstance.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/ec2-metricscollected.html) for more info.

Next, reboot the instance and try stop starting and reconnect via SSH. Check you application logs (if any) and check your [Apache Logs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored) and [Linux Logs](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/linux-var-log-files/) to see what happened.

But to answer your question, what typically causes a instance to freeze up like this:

- Bad Application code that sucks up all the CPU overloading the instance
- Too much traffic overloading the instance
- Running too many services on the instance that it's unable to handle
- AWS Hardware problem - Uncommon